# reversing the boolean return type from a function

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have two functions which accept a function type: `Int => Boolean` function type

```
def myFunction1(f1: Int => Boolean) ...
def myFunction2(f2: Int => Boolean) ...
```

I want to call function2 from function1 but instead of just invoking it with f1, I want to invoke it with the inverse of f1.  So if f1 is something like

```
(x: Int) => x > 4
```

at runtime, i.e. return true for numbers greater than four. I want the reverse returns false if numbers are greater than four.  Is it possible to inverse f1 before calling myFunction2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
def myFunction1(f1: Int => Boolean) =  myFunction2(!f1(_))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def myFunction1(f1: Int => Boolean) =  myFunction2(f1 andThen (! _))
```